# Custom Ribbon Action - Disabled with Selecting Document Set

Tags: 2013, javascript

The custom action enables/disables when a list item or folder is selected/deselected. The issue I'm running into is when a document set is selected, the custom action remains disabled.

The logic:

```
Single Item Selected: enabled
Multiple Items Selected: disabled
Folder Selected: disabled
Document Set Selected: enabled

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <CustomAction
  Id="LinkDocsCustom"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
  RegistrationType="ContentType"
  RegistrationId="0x01">
 <CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Groups._children">
      <Group
          Id="LinkDocsCustomGroup"
          Sequence="15"
          Description="Copy permanent link to clipboard"
          Title="Permanent Link"
          Template="LinkDocsCustomGroupTemplate">
        <Controls Id="LinkDocsCustomGroupControl">
          <Button
              Id="LinkDocsCustomGroupControlButton"
              Sequence="5"
              Command="SimpleAlert"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Left="-448" Image32by32Top="-128"
              Description="Copies a permanent link to the clipboard"
              LabelText="Copy Link to Clipboard"
              ToolTipTitle="Copy Link to Clipboard"
              TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </Controls>
      </Group>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
      <GroupTemplate Id="LinkDocsCustomGroupTemplate">
        <Layout Title="LargeLarge">
          <OverflowSection Type="OneRow" TemplateAlias="o1" DisplayMode="Large"/>
          <OverflowSection Type="OneRow" TemplateAlias="o2" DisplayMode="Large"/>
        </Layout>
      </GroupTemplate>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Scaling._children">
      <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.Documents.Scaling.Custom.MaxSize" Sequence="15" GroupId="LinkDocsCustomGroup" Size="LargeLarge" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="SimpleAlert"
      CommandAction="javascript:CopyLinkToClipboard();"
      EnabledScript="javascript:EnableCopyLinkToClipboard();"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>

<CustomAction
 Id="CopyLinkToClipboardScript"
 Location="ScriptLink"
 ScriptSrc ="/_layouts/15/CustomMenuAction/CopyLinkToClipboard.js"/>
</Elements>
```

JavaScript:

```
// This method contains the code needed to request the unique url to the document
function CopyLinkToClipboard() {
// First get the context and web
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.web = ctx.get_web();

var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var sdlist = this.web.get_lists().getById(listId);

var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
var mijnid = items[0];


this.listItem = sdlist.getItemById(mijnid.id);
// load the item in the context for batch operation.
ctx.load(this.listItem);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,    this.onQuerySucceeded),               
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}


function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var url = this.listItem.get_item('_dlc_DocIdUrl').get_url();
// Request the name of the document. 
var title = this.listItem.get_item('FileLeafRef');
// Copy Link To Clipboard (Only works in Internet Explorer)
window.clipboardData.setData('Text', url);
// Notify the user that the link was successfully copied
var notificationId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Link Copied');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('failed ' + args.toString());
}


function EnableCopyLinkToClipboard() {
var enable = true;
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selection = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

// Check if more than one item is selected, disable the button if items > 1
if (CountDictionary(selection) == 1)
    this.enable = true;
else
    return false;
// Check if a folder is selected
var item;
for (item in selection) {
    if (selection[item].fsObjType != 0)
        enable = false;
}
return enable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document set is a folder, so your `selection[item].fsObjType` check will return the same value for folders and document sets.

What you probably could do in your `if (selection[item].fsObjType != 0)` is to make a call to check the `ContentType` property of the item you have selected, if you use the OOTB Document Set content type you could simply confirm the name (`get_name()`). If its a child of it etc, you'll have do dig into the parent object of it etc. Maybe there is another way, but only thing I could think of.

**Edit:**

You have to make a call to the list and the item to get the ContentType property.Here is a quick and dirty example on the flow I was thinking of, you probably have to rewrite some, but you get the point:

Changed this in your `EnableCopyLinkToClipboard()` function:

```
for (item in selection) {
    if (selection[item].fsObjType != 0)         
    {   
        CheckIfDocumentSet().done(function(val){
            return val;
        });

    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the `CheckIfDocumentSet` function could look something like this:

```
function CheckIfDocumentSet() {
 var dfd = $.Deferred();
    _CheckIfDocumentSet(dfd);
 return dfd.promise();
}

function _CheckIfDocumentSet(dfd) {

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.web = ctx.get_web();

    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var sdlist = this.web.get_lists().getById(listId);

    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var mijnid = items[0];


    var listItem = sdlist.getItemById(mijnid.id);

    ctx.load(listItem, "ContentType");

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        if(listItem.get_contentType().get_name() === "Document Set")
        {
            dfd.resolve(true);
        }
        else { dfd.resolve(false); }

    }, function() {dfd.reject(); });

}
```

Note that I have just copy/pasted from your other functions and not made it look nice/optimal etc, just made i work :) And you need jQuery for the `$.Deferred` object

**Updated My Script**

```
function CheckIfDocumentSet() {
var dfd = $.Deferred();
_CheckIfDocumentSet(dfd);
return dfd.promise();
}

function _CheckIfDocumentSet(dfd) {

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.web = ctx.get_web();

var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var sdlist = this.web.get_lists().getById(listId);

var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
var mijnid = items[0];


var listItem = sdlist.getItemById(mijnid.id);

ctx.load(listItem, "ContentType");

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    if (listItem.get_contentType().get_name() === "Document Set") {
        dfd.resolve(true);
    }
    else { dfd.resolve(false); }

}, function () { dfd.reject(); });

}

// Method to enable/disable the button on the ribbon or ECB. 
function EnableCopyLinkToClipboard() {
var enable = true;

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selection = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

// Check if more than one item is selected, disable the button if items > 1
if (CountDictionary(selection) == 1)
    this.enable = true;
else
    return false;
// Check if a folder is selected
var item;
for (item in selection) {
    if (selection[item].fsObjType != 0) {
        CheckIfDocumentSet().done(function (val) {
            return val;
        });

    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have made a couple of changes to  check the content type, but I think I may be missing a step. The error is "Object doesn't support property or method 'get_contentType". The change to the code:  var _contentType = item.get_contentType();
    for (item in selection) {
     alert(_contentType);
        if (selection[item]._contentType != 'Document')
            enable = false;

Comment: @Jason updated my answer, hope it helps you out some

Comment: after making the suggested changes, I'm getting an alert with the value of 0, when an item is selected.

Comment: your suggestions were a huge help in resolving the issues I was having.